# ClickOnce Settings Not Found When Run from Command Line

Tags: winforms, command-line-interface, clickonce

I have a Windows Forms app that is deployed through ClickOnce.  In the app, I take advantage of the application settings to store basic connection information.  In the two years and 200+ updates since I've published the app and it's been in daily use, I've had no problems with individual users modifying their own settings, and having those settings retained when the application is relaunched and updated.

However, I am working on adding a feature into the app that allows for certain tasks to be scheduled in the Task Scheduler.  Everything works fine (the task is scheduled, and the application is called with the correct parameters passed) however when the program is launched, the settings are not read.

I can replicate this by manually launching the application directly from the command line.  The application opens, but the only settings available are the settings that shipped with the application initially.

My end question is this: **How can I call my ClickOnce app from the command line and have it open the same way as if I'd launched it from the start menu?**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to point the Task Scheduler to launch the .appref-ms file that is found in the start menu shortcut.  You can't just point to the .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the Command line launching the ClickOnce App under a different user.

Try launching the ClickOnce from Command line or Task scheduler, and loading up task manager and seeing which user the app is running. If it is running on a user other than the user you are logged in as, then you can either log in as the user it is running under (if it's not a system user) and setting what settings you want, or you could try impersonating the desired user through task scheduler.

If none of that is applicable, you could add a Command line switch that, if no settings are found, saves a set of default settings that match what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it really made me think about it, but no.  When I run the app (either through the command line or through the task scheduler) it shows that I am the user that called it.  When the task was created, by default the task is set to run under my username only.

Comment: When you run the app through command or Task scheduler, does the clickonce application update when there is an update?

Comment: Short answer - Yes.

Comment: Long answer - You can't call the .appref-ms file directly from the TaskScheduler AND pass arguments.  I have to have the TS call a batch file which in turn calls the .appref-ms file along with arguments.  Asinine, I know, but it works.  Working this way give me the same functionality as it the user had opened the program from the start menu.  I do have the auto-update feature turned on, so if there is an update available, as of now, the program will hang waiting for user interaction.  I'll have to remove the auto update from ClickOnce and code it manually.